# Proof of the Solovay Theorem in Jech

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

The Solovay Theorem says:

> Let $\kappa$ be a regular uncountable cardinal. Then every stationary subset is the disjoint union of $\kappa$-many stationary subsets. [Jech, Theorem 8.8, p. 95]

One step in Jech's proof of this theorem I do not understand (underlined in red in the picture below). Why is $D$ a closed unbounded set?

[image: Proof of the Solovay Theorem in Jech]

Comment: Do you understand why $D$ is closed? Or why it's unbounded?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Maybe unboundedness comes from the assumption that $W$ is a stationary set of regular cardinals? And closure by the definition of $D$? But... I find the concepts pretty hard to get an intuitive grasp!

Comment: Why is $C$ a set of regular cardinals?

Comment: @AsafKaragila My idea was: $W$ is a stationary set, hence $\sup W = \kappa$ (unbounded). Also, because $\gamma \in W$ is regular, $\eta(\xi) < \gamma$ for all $\xi < \gamma$. But I now realize that is not true. So I'm back to square one.

Comment: I feel I just do not know enough about the $\eta(\xi)$.

Comment: For comparison see the proof in Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs, by K. Kunen. It's the same proof but Kunen's style of explication is quite different.